# Trouble opening a WP7 .XAP file from another computer

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

Am trying to open a .xap file that I created from my computer on another computer but am having trouble. Am getting an error message that package is invalid or corrupt. When I use my computer the .xap file is opening fine without any hitches.

How do I get around this problem because I do not always carry around the computer.

Comment: .xap files are just .zip files under a different extension. Can you open it in 7zip (or similar)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the .xap extension to a .zip extension. Or rightclick and open with 7zip/winrar or another program that supports the .zip format. If that still doesn't work, the file is probably corrupted, and you have to copy it again.